# Laravel login using id session regenerate

Tags: laravel, authentication, token

I can't login using id user because my session always regenerate when I do it. How I can fix it?

PHP code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

EDIT:

I did it:

1. I installed clean laravel 6.0
2. I connected to database and migrated tables.
3. I added user in table users with ID 1 and other information
4. I writed in web routes(file: routes/web.php) this:

PHP code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

     auth()->loginUsingId(1);

     if (auth()->check()) { 
           echo 'TRUE';
     }
     else
     {
           echo 'FALSE';
     } 
});
```

RESULT IS TRUE...

But when I commented authenticating, I get FALSE. Why?

PHP code:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

     //auth()->loginUsingId(1);

     if (auth()->check()) { 
           echo 'TRUE';
     }
     else
     {
           echo 'FALSE';
     } 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put code in code boxes ...

Comment: It would also be interesting why you want to keep the old token. You can find the source [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L387).

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen why user authenticating not saved after reloading page? After reloading created new session file.

Comment: @SashaSasha Unfortunately I got a little confused now. What is exactly the problem? Now it sounds like you have a problem that the user is not logged in after navigating to a different page. Try to update your question with as much detail as youu can.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen I edited my question. Please help me

Comment: @SashaSasha Can you add the output of `php artisan route:list`. A first guess would be that your route does not have the `web` middleware. The `web` middleware is a group of multiple middlewares including the middleware that provides the feature to handle sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision:

If we use authorization verification immediately after authorization, a new session is created.

So after authorization we cannot use

```
    Auth::check()
```

because authorization after reloading the page will disappear.